# Execute two commands if the first one fails

Tags: shell

I am writing a script.sh like:

```
ls a || ls > /dev/null || echo "both command fails"; exit 3
echo 5 # not showed up
```

I hope the `exit 3` be only executed when both command1 and command2 failed. But it seems that even if `ls > /dev/null` is ok, the `exit 3` still fired thus makes `echo 5` never showed up.

Anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: which shell are you using?  answers vary.

Comment: you need to do `{ echo "both command fails"; exit 3; }`

Comment: bash of Macintosh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `||` binds tighter than `;`, so your first line consists of two commands: the first is a compound command: `ls || ls || echo` and the second is just `exit 3`. As mentioned in a comment by meuh, you should write

```
ls a || ls > /dev/null || { echo "both command fails"; exit 3; }
echo 5 # not showed up
```